# Meu código Python funciona, mas não entendo o porquê de um int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz um programa para cálculo de tempo de medicações. De acordo com os cálculos está tudo rodando perfeitamente, mas eu não entendi um detalhe, o porquê da necessidade de usar um `int()` em determinado momento.

Podem me explicar? Segue o código completo e abaixo a parte específica do 'problema':

```
# utf -8
import shutil

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
print("Olá, Rafaela, vamos calcular quantos dias seus medicamentos irão durar!".center(columns))

quantidade1 = float((input("Quantos comprimidos de 300MG você possui? ")))
quantidade2 = float((input("Quantos comprimidos de 600MG você possui? ")))
dosagem = float((input("Quantos MG você toma diariamente? ")))

total_mg = (quantidade1 * 300) + (quantidade2 * 600)

dias = (total_mg / dosagem)
meses = int((dias / 30))

if dias < 30:
    print("Seus medicamentos irão durar %.2f dias!".center(columns) % dias)
elif 60 > dias >= 30:
    dias -= 30
    print("Seus medicamentos irão durar %d mês e %d dias!".center(columns) % (meses, dias))
else:
    dias = dias - (meses * 30)
    print("Seus medicamentos irão durar %d meses e %d dias!".center(columns) % (meses, dias))
```

A questão é: se na linha 14 eu retirar o `int()`, o `else` simplesmente para de funcionar adequadamente e todas as respostas serão X meses e 0 dias (sempre 0 dias), mas eu não entendi o porquê. Alguém consegue me explicar?

```
meses = int((dias / 30))
```

Aqui está o exemplo do output do código com e sem `int()`, para o `else`, com os `inputs()` sendo , respectivamente, 240, 450 e 1500.

`Seus medicamentos irão durar 7 meses e 18 dias!`  usando `int()`

`Seus medicamentos irão durar 7 meses e 0 dias!`   não usando `int()`

Comment: Porque você está fazendo o casting de float para inteiro. Seu print está usando %d para mostrar o número, que espera um inteiro. Tente trocar de %d para %.2f assim como fez acima e tirar o int.

Comment: Se foi você que escreveu o código, recomendo fortemente rever o seu processo de desenvolvimento. O natural é primeiro você entender o problema e a partir disso elaborar a solução; não elaborar uma solução para a partir dela buscar entender o problema, como fez.

Comment: Troquei para %.2f e tirei o int, mas o problema voltou! _Seus medicamentos irão durar 822463 meses e 0.00 dias!_

Comment: Quanto ao processo de desenvolvimento, eu entendo o ponto, mas é só porquê estava tentando por em prática o que aprendi sobre Control Flow mesmo e parecia tudo ok, mas excepcionalmente o else não batia com o resultado esperado. Mexi em todos os cálculos pensando que eram a causa, mas no fim acabou sendo esse int.

Comment: A função `int()` retira todos os valores após o ".". Ela serve para transformar um valor para inteiro de base decimal, o que acaba truncando os valores para 0 casas decimais. Então, ao invés de ser _"3.5 meses"_, o correto para mostrar para o usuário seria _"3 meses e 15 dias"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está na última condição, mais precisamente em `dias = dias - (meses * 30)` (o qual você pode simplificar para `dias -= (meses * 30)`).

Se você não forçar com que meses seja um inteiro (usando `int()`), `dias -= (meses * 30)` **sempre** será igual a zero (uma vez que `dias = meses * 30`).

Com o exemplo que você deu, `meses = 7.6` e `meses = int(7.6) = 7`. Percebe a diferença? Sempre é interessante checar a documentação oficial se tiver dúvidas dos comportamentos de [funções built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int).

Ainda com o seu exemplo, `dias = 228.0`. Logo, `228.0 -= 7.6*30 = 0` e `228.0 -= 7*30 = 18`.

Comment: Caraca, muito obrigado! Quebrei um pouco a cabeça mas entendi, no final das contas eu acabei cometendo o erro de lógica ao multiplicar `meses * 30` que nada mais foi o contrário do que eu tinha feito antes e os dois acabavam se subtraindo. Também percebi que se eu colocar `dias -= (int(meses) * 30)` só nesta linha, também viria a funcionar. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @AlecsanderCamilo se a resposta lhe ajudou, aceite-a